# Program Design: Using Android dialog boxes in a serialized way

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement something in Android but I can't seem to think of a good design of what I want to do. Problem can be summarized as the following.

There are two boolean flags "FlagA" and "FlagB".
After calling a function like "doProccessing", in order

```
if FlagA, display dialog box and do some stuff based on yes no
if FlagB, display dialog box and do some stuff based on yes no
do final processing after the above two are done.
```

I can use alert dialog boxes and onClickListeners for all that stuff, but I don't see the right way to serialize these actions. I can't always just chain the dialog boxes together as box A or B might not be displayed at all. Doing thread wait() and notify() calls is kinda gross and I bet there is a better way. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% **certain** you need dialogs? Most cases where you would think to use a dialog, you should use a notification instead. Most of the rest of the cases, you should just stuff into the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You could have doProcessing set a counter to either 0, 1, 2 based on how many dialog boxes need to be displayed, then the onClickListeners will count it down. When the counter reaches 0 an event will fire that triggers a handler in your activity to do the final processing. Not 100% how to monitor the counter, maybe Observer/Observable could be of some use?